# Logging with java.util.logging in a multi thread application

Tags: java, logging, saf

I have a swing application based on SAF (Swing Application Framework). All logging is done via java.util.logging and two different handlers: console and file.
When I create Action to be executed by background taks, these task do not logging does not show up on console or file, even if here is no error/exception when calling the logger.log() method.

Is there any problem in using java.utils.logging classes from different threads? How may I better check/resolv this problem?

Thanks,
Giuseppe

Comment: i hv same problem,did u fix it?

Answer (score 0):

java.util.logging works safely in a multi-threaded application.

You should create a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try to produce a simple example.